# PHP form stopped working after validation added

Tags: php, forms, validation

First question here so thanks in advance!

The submit form I am attempting to correct stopped working after integrating a validation script. It appears to work although the mail is never sent.

HTML:

```
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/**
  * Basic jQuery Validation Form Demo Code
  * Copyright Sam Deering 2012
  * Licence: http://www.jquery4u.com/license/
  */
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#contactform").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    phone: "required",
                    comment: "required",
               },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    phone: "Please enter a valid email phone number",
                    comment: "Please enter your reason for inquiry"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

The Form:

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" id="contactform">

    <div id="form-content">
        <fieldset>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="firstname">First Name*</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name*</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="email">Email*</label>
                <input type="text" name="email">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="phone">Phone*</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone">
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <label for="comment">Reason for Inquiry*</label>
                <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="fieldgroup">
                <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

send_form_email.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "donliggett@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Web Submission";

    $first_name = $_POST['firstname']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $reason = $_POST['comment']; // required

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Reason for Inquiry: ".clean_string($reason)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
```

Thanks guys and gals, huge fan of StackOverflow!

Comment: I do not think it has to do with javascript validation ... do the values pass corectly in `$_POST` try `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: You should check in your PHP file, not only with jQuery. And the function clean_string is quite useless, way to easy to bypass. Check all user input properly in your PHP file.

Comment: The values do in fact pass. It does not push the mail though. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to do with jQuery validation, you just forgot a `}` at the end of `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`

Before `?>` add `}`

Comment: I'm sorry Mihai, I forgot to copy/paste that part. It's in the syntax after my HTML. I even moved the "}" above the HTML to no success. Your help is very much appreciated. Anything else look conflicting?

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST)` to see if you get the values correct

Comment: The values do in fact pass. It does not push the mail though. :(

Comment: then it has something to do with your `mail()` function

Comment: Wow, super sad-face. Spam folder was gobbling up my web submissions.

Answer (score 0):

Before your last ?> put another }  ;)